# onclick function has undefined caller object

Tags: javascript

I have read other questions on similar issues, but their solutions have not worked for me. 
Here is my call to the function:

```
<li class="">
<a href="#" class="" onclick="updateProjectData(this, $ID, $Latitude, $Longitude)">
<span class="text">$Title</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Here is my function:

```
function updateProjectData(caller, pid, lat, long)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "...",
        data: "projectID=" + pid,
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery('#buildingDetails').fadeOut(200).html(data).fadeIn(200);
            $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    if ($('.imagefader').length) {
                        $('.imagefader').innerfade({
                            speed: 'slow',
                            timeout: 4000,
                            type: 'sequence',
                            containerheight: '245px'
                        });
                    }
                    //make the clicked a and li current
                    $('a').removeClass('current');
                    $('li').removeClass('current');
                    caller.addClass('current');
                    caller.parentNode.addClass('current');
                }
            );
        }
    });
    //tried it here too!
}
```

I have also tried taking the caller references out of the ajax call, but always get an 'undefined is not an object ' error.

Comment: What is `ID, $Latitude, $Longitude` ? Where have you defined it ?

Comment: That bit works fine. It is silverstripe cms. Is the caller class modifications that don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You've misinterpreted the error message. `caller` isn't `undefined` but `caller.addClass` is.

`caller` is a DOM element and `addClass` is a jQuery method.

You either need `caller.classList.add("current")` or `jQuery(caller).addClass("current")`.

Comment: Thanks :)  You earned my virgin tick!